# YUI DataTable Pagination

Tags: yui

Does YUI (3.7)'s DataTable support pagination? It's mentioned in the API docs - but only in the code example. When I try to find any in-depth documentation, I couldn't see anything.

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/DataTable.html

But this suggests that it might not be supported yet (although I understand it's referring to a slightly older version)

http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=32211

Thanks

Comment: There is a gallery module for pagination, you can see examples here: http://blunderalong.com/yui/dti/paginator/

Comment: Thanks, That link isn't working for me but I get the idea and will have a dig around that site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of paginator modules in the gallery, most of which work with YUI DataTable, but there is no official Y.Paginator in YUI yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll look into those tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

There's a gallery module for datatable pagination: http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/datatable-paginator

Also you can use [AlloyUI Pagination](http://alloyui.com/examples/pagination) with [DataTable](http://alloyui.com/examples/datatable): https://gist.github.com/zenorocha/5032360

Answer (score 1):

Y.Paginator now exists. But it is very low-level and contains no UI components. [see](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/paginator/).

There's also a very un-documented `Datatable.Paginator` class. Which I can't figure out at all. [Link](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/DataTable.Paginator.html).